# .net using client certificate in webbrowser (skip select dialog)

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, client-certificates

Hi I'm trying to skip select certificate dialog in webbrowser control (https).

Is there any way to automatically select specified certificate (from installed ones) to log in with?

Just like this dialog:

[image]

I have more certificates I'm working with, so I can't disable them.

I tried sendkeys to navigate between installed certificates, but to do this the app has to stay topmost.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with FindWindowEx and SendMessage functions.